# How to know which of the Magento Pages is the active homepage?

Tags: magento2

[image]

I'm new to Magento. It looks like there's no label which of the pages is the homepage.

How would I know which of the pages in the screenshot is the active homepage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't look it up in the CMS Page Area.

In the Menu, go to:

Stores > Configuration > General > Web > Default Pages > CMS Home Page